# Do I need to use "global" for every variable I use between two different <?php ?> tags?

Tags: php, variables, global

For example:

```
<?php $foo = 'blah'; ?>

<?php echo $foo; ?>
```

Do I need to put a `global $foo;` before the `echo` in the second `<?php ?>`?

Comment: if its a method, you could pass in the variable as an argument

Comment: You should try to avoid using global variables and the `global` keyword as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, that will work fine as is.
You only need to use global when the variable is accessed in a function/class or otherwise not in the immediate scope it was declared in.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't. You actually don't even have to use the global keyword if you use the variable in an included file.

E.g.:

file1.php

```
<?php
$foo = 'a variable';
include 'file2.php';
?>
```

file2.php

```
<?php
// here you can use the $foo variable, as it was declared before the inclusion
echo $foo;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In normal situations the only use of "global" keyword is inside of a function's scope and for using a global variable inside the local scope of a function. for example:

```
<?php
    $globalVariable = 2;
    function myFunction()
    {
        global $globalVariable;

        return $globalVariable;
    }
?>
```

However, using global keyword outside of a function is allowed, because you may include a file from inside of a function.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to do this.
The use of `global` keyword is only needed when you're changing the variable scope. There's a chapter in PHP manual, that describes the variable scope and the `global` keyword. This lecture will help you to understand the topic: [Variable scope in PHP manual](http://php.net/language.variables.scope.php).